# Is there anyway to verify a google spreadsheets ID's

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So don't crucify me too badly if this is a dumb question,

But I've been dabbling in Google App Scripts, mainly its uses within Google sheets.
Generally when I've been using `openById()`
If it's an ID that might change regularly, I'll put it at  the top of my script and add notes on how to edit (for the user i hand sheet over to, or for me as a reminder if i've not worked on it for a bit and i forget). If's pretty stangnant and not likely to change, I'll just declare it as a var.

I was thinking it's a bit more user friendly to have a "settings" sheet within the spreadsheet and the user inputs the settings. Rather than having to go into script editor to edit things.

But even via sheet, or script editor, a single thing added or removed in the wrong place can cause havock, like a space or /

At least with a "settings" sheet, you can use data validation and regular expressions to control and reject what the user inputs.

So I guess my question is Google Sheets ID's seem alien to me, bar length,  and I was wondering is there any way to validate the ID's using regular expressions or something, rather than checking the ID server side.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why does the file ID ever change?  I don't think there's any way to check whether a file ID is valid without using server side code.  But calling the server is quite fast.  You can use JavaScript `myString.trim()` to remove whitespace from both sides of a string.  A sheet for user settings would definitely be better than going into the script editor.  You could create a menu, and a dialog box to force users to enter a certain way.

Comment: Yes. Must check server side by tring to open it. It will fail if its bad or script doesnt have permission

Comment: File ID might change, if a new spreadsheet is created monthly/quarterly.
So no way via regexpression, to validate ID :(
If i had something like `IF(SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID HERE)=False/Null){Browser.msgBox("Your spreadsheet ID is wrong, please check it");}` (not 100% sure off the top of my head what a bad open command would return)
That would be the best sort of check without regexpression

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.openById("gibberish") will only return an exception, unfortunately. so you have use try...catch as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use openByUrl() in your scripts, so users can just paste a link.

but if you must validate the ID:

```js
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function validate(){
  //"sheetRef" is the name of the cell where you enter the id
  //this function takes the string value of "sheetRef" 
  //and replaces it with the validation result.
  var sheetRefCell = ss.getRangeByName("sheetRef");
  var sheetRefString = sheetRefCell.getValue();
  var validationResult = '{' + sheetRefString + '}';

  try {
    validationResult = validationResult + 
      ' \n $ references: \n [' + 
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetRefString).getName() +
      ']';
  } 
  catch (e) {
    validationResult = validationResult +
    ' \n $  is an invalid reference: \n [' + 
      e +
    ']';
  }
  finally {
    sheetRefCell.setValue(validationResult);
  }
}
```

when you run this it will replace the value entered in your 'sheetRef' (ID) cell with the validation result message. I recommend that you also add a time-based trigger to contininuously revalidate your ID.

Then you can add another cell to your spreadsheet which will extract the validated ID from 'sheetRef'. This cell should contain the formula:

```
     = IF (IFERROR( SEARCH( 'invalid' , sheetRef ), 0 ) > 0,
           "Invalid", 
           IFERROR( REGEXEXTRACT( sheetRef,"{(.*?)}" ), "Undetermined" )
        )
```

So the cell with the above formula will EITHER display a valid id or "Invalid"/"Undetermined".

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I'll give that a try.
But I'm guessing its a big fat no to verifying ID's anyway else.
There isn't a standard naming convention that google ID's use that can be verified client side, via regular expression.

Comment: they are random ids, of varying length, limited to numbers and chars. you could add validation rule that asks for characters and numbers only, but I really dont see any point.